# Python: Fitting lines to alle the decreasing parts of my data (max to min) and extrapolate them (max to max)?

Tags: python, pandas, linear-interpolation

I have daily water level measurements (hydraulic head) over several years (stored in a series with datetime index). I'm trying to fit a line to all the decreasing parts of the data. These straight lines should then be extrapolated until the next max of the data. If the first point is a minimum I want to fit a straight line till the next max. This is illustrated in the picture below.

I managed to code this problem in Python but in a very "ugly" way using 150 lines of code (lot of if statements).

My approach: smooth the data by fitting splines. Then use `find_peaks` of `scipy.signal` to find the extremas (multiply by -1 to get min). As this function does not deal with the first and the last point I used if statements to deal with this. Then I use two for loops to do the curve fitting and the extrapolation. I used one for loop in case the data starts with a min and another in case the data starts with a max as the boundaries of my "fit interval" and my "extrapolation interval" differ for each case. In case the data starts with a min I used a straight line for the first interval. The result of my code is shown in the image.

[Image showing result of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OY1a.png)

Any ideas how to do this in a better way? Without using so many lines of code

The following code snippet shows my approach for the case where the data starts with a maximum

```
    #hydraulic_head is a series of interpolated (spline) hydraulic head measurements with a datetime index

    from scipy.signal import find_peaks
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np

    peak_max=hydraulic_head[find_peaks(hydraulic_head)[0]] #hydraulic head at max
    peak_min=hydraulic_head[find_peaks(hydraulic_head*-1)[0]] #hydraulic head at min


   for gr in range(1,len(peak_max.index),1):

    interval_fit=hydraulic_head[peak_max.index[gr-1]:peak_min.index[gr-1]] #interval to fit curve from max to min
    t_fit=(interval_fit.index-interval_fit.index[0]).total_seconds().values #time in seconds

    parameters=np.polyfit(t_fit,interval_max_min.values,1) #fit a line
    parameter_estimated[gr]=parameterss #store the paramters of the line in a dict

    interval_extrapolate=hydraulic_head[peak_max.index[gr-1]:peak_max.index[gr]] #interval to extrapolate
    t_extrapolate=(interval_extrapolate.index-interval_extrapolate.index[0]).total_seconds().values #transform to time

    values_extrapolated=parameters[0]*t_extrapolate+parameters[1] #extrapolate the line
    new_index=interval_extrapolate.index #get the index from the extrapolated interval
    new_series=pd.DataFrame(data=values_extrapolated,index=new_index,columns=['extrapolated']) #new data frame with extrapolated values

    interpolation_out=pd.concat([interpolation_out,new_series]) #growing frame where lines are stored
```

Possible other approach: Using masks to find the intervals, numerate them and then posibily use groupby to extract the intervals. I didn't manage to do it this way.

It's my first question here. Open for any improvement on question formulation